# Helper class sessionHelper could not be found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

When trying to run CakePHP based application I'm getting following error:

```
2014-01-25 11:46:21 Error: [MissingHelperException] Helper class sessionHelper could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'sessionHelper',
  'plugin' => false,
)
```

It occurred when I copied CakePHP application to production server. I never had error like this in any of previous developed CakePHP applications.

Just to mention that Session helper is loaded in AppController. PHP version on server is 5.3.10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to include `SessionHelper` instead of `sessionHelper`

```
public $helpers = array('Session');
```

If the production server is on unix, this is important.

Answer (score 0):

Include `SessionHelper` as cornelb said. And be careful when calling Session helper manually, just **call it with capital 'S'**:

```
$this->Session->read('Auth.User');
```